# Get "users without specific row "

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I have a table that holds information about registered users. Something similar to this:

```
umeta_id | user_id | meta_key    | meta_value
---------|---------|-------------|-------------
 1       | 1       | nickname    | value
 2       | 1       | first_name  | value
 3       | 1       | custom_key  | value
 4       | 2       | nickname    | value
 5       | 2       | first_name  | value
 6       | 3       | nickname    | value
 7       | 3       | first_name  | value
 8       | 3       | custom_key  | value
```

There are two forms to register, so the row count that corresponds to a registered user varies depending on which form is used when registering.

For example, if a user used form A to register, there's a row with `custom_key` that's associated with that user. If the user used form B, there's no `custom_key` row. Compare the rows with `user_id` `1` and `2`. `1` registered using form A, and `2` registered using form B.

I can get the users with `custom_key` (that used form A), but how do I get the users that used form B, that is, users without `custom_key` row?

This `SELECT * FROM rfs_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'custom_key'` returns rows/users that used form A. I need to do the opposite.

In JS, I'd write it as:

```js
var users = {};

// loop usermeta rows
for (var row in rfs_usermeta) {
    // group rows with same user_id
    users[row.user_id][row.meta_key] = value;
}

var result = [];

// loop grouped rows
for (var user in users) {
    // assume users don't have custom_key row
    var rowExists = false;
    // loop user keys
    for (var key in user) {
        // check if custom_key exists 
        if (key == "custom_key") {
            // mark current user
            rowExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // ignore marked users
    if (!rowExists) {
        result.push(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the mystery downvoter care to explain his/her reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  rfs_usermeta 
WHERE user_id NOT IN( SELECT user_id FROM rfs_usermeta WHERE meta_key='custom_key')
```

You never want to filter with PHP if you can filter with your database. Your database is designed to gather/order/filter data and can do this *super* fast, where a PHP loop is a lot slower.

Comment: up-voted as it is the easiest and simplest solution.

Comment: I think `SELECT user_id WHERE` shoud be `SELECT user_id FROM rfs_usermeta WHERE`. Also I changed `SELECT *` into `SELECT DISTINCT user_id` to get just ids.

Answer (score 1):

SQL operates best in set based approaches:  Given that obtain a set of data for all users.  and a set of data for users with the custom key.  Then basically subtract the two:  All users less those with custom key = users w/o custom key.

a correlated subquery and not exists.

Simply get a set of users that have custom key.  Then a set of all records except those in the set having custom key.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rfs_usermeta A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM rfs_usermeta B
                  WHERE A.umeta_id = B.umeta_id 
                    and B.meta_key = 'custom_key')
```

A left join would also work  similar premise

```
SELECT * 
FROM rfs_usermeta A
LEFT JOIN rfs_usermeta B
 on A.umeta_id = B.umeta_id 
and B.meta_ket = 'custom_key'
WHERE B.user_ID is null
```

Comment: That would depend on indexes, table sizes records etc... LEFT Join, Not exists, not in are the 3 standard approaches.

Comment: If you have the proper indexes it's not. If you think I'm incorrect, please provide documentation

Comment: It is a BIG IF.

Comment: I use to think that because I like the readability of not in; but too many factors go into making a good decision to say one is "faster" than another. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join  "for the pattern of finding all rows in table A where some condition does not exist in table B, NOT EXISTS is typically going to be your best choice. But, as always, you need to test these patterns in your own environment, using your schema, data and hardware, and mixed in with your own workloads."

Comment: It also depends on version of compiler and database;  like I said soo many factors to determine which is "best"  but when is good.... good enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM rfs_usermeta r
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rfs_usermeta r2 where r2.user_id = r.user_id 
meta_key = 'custom_key') = 0
```

Comment: This won't work because there are 20+ rows that's associated with a single user.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `r` and `r2`? Are they variables? I haven't used anything like that before.

Comment: (this is why I am a fan of the ` tablename AS tbl` syntax)

Comment: @akinuri  r and r2 are table aliases meant to improve readability and save typing.  Since the table rfs_usermeta is referenced twice; one needs to distinguish which columns one is referencing and since we can't reuse rfs_usermeta, aliases are used.  R is just 1 instance of rfs_usermeta and r2 is another instance of rfs_usermeta but each instance has it's own "set" of data.